# Getting/creating relational data on the fly in MySQL/MariaDB

Tags: mysql

I'm developing a distributable application that logs event data to a MySQL database. Some of the data it logs is redundant, like who caused the event, etc. A dumb example might be `user: bob`, `action: created`, `target: file123`

The schema is normalized so instead of storing `bob` every time, I'd store `user_id`. The problem I have is that my app is merely a layer that other applications would send data to so I won't always have a user record before I need to log an event.

To accommodate this, I wrote a "get or create" procedure that checks if that user exists, if so returns the `user_id`, otherwise creates a new entry and returns the generated key. (I had tried `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` but it doesn't play well with auto-increment primary keys in this scenario, it kept generating a new key).

For example, I might use:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getOrCreateUser(IN `username` VARCHAR(25), OUT `userId` INT(11))
BEGIN
    SELECT user_id INTO `userId` FROM users WHERE username = `username`;

    IF `userId` IS NULL THEN
        INSERT INTO users (`username`) VALUES (`username`);
        SET `userId` = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    END IF;
END
```

Now, when `INSERT`ing an `event` I can `CALL getOrCreateUser(...)` to ensure that user record exists.

This *works* but I'm wondering if this is a wise approach. Say the application batch inserts 1000 event records, this would be called 1000 times.

The only way to reduce that is to call this *once* and cache the `username/userId` key/value pair in memory.

I just feel like there are two issues with that approach:

1. That could become inefficient if I have 100k users.
2. With proper indexes maybe an in-memory `Map` isn't much better?
3. Some other problem I'm not thinking of...

I've never taken this approach and am looking for insight from more experienced MySQL devs.

Comment: MariaDB and MySQL aren't identical. Which are you actually using? Please specify the version, especially if it's MySQL.

Comment: For the purposes of this, let's just say MySQL 8+. Users will provide their own DB server. I can specify version requirements and if needed I can drop MariaDB support or possibly write it separately.

Comment: Don't use the `@` character in your variable names, that just confuses people because it looks like a [user-defined variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html), which is a different thing from a procedure input variable or local variable that you create with DEFINE. I see a lot of posts on Stack Overflow from people who get these different types of variables mixed up. Adding a literal `@` character to your procedure input variables is just making the confusion worse.